# In android, A ListView Contains a TextView, and how to set minHeight for TextView

Tags: android-listview

I have a ListItem with TextView.I set the minHeight of TextView as follows.

**list_item_forecast.xml**

```
<TextView ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id = "@+id/list_item_forecast_textView"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

and the fragment file xml is as follows.

**fragment_main.xml**

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ForecastFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView_forecast"
/>
```

Even though I set the minHeight of textView to "?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" , I am seeing the output on device as follows.

***This the code in fragment.java. Need to display forecastArrayAdapter String data in ListView***

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    String[] forecastArray = new String[]{"Today - Sunny - 86/83",
            "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/46",
            "Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
            "Thurs - Rainy - 64/51",
            "Fri - Foggy - 70/46",
            "Sat - Sunny - 76/68",
            "Sun - Sunny - 20/7"};

    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                                                                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textView,weekForecast );

    ListView listView =  (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

Could someone help me out setting the minHeight for each text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I can't see any `TextView` in your **list_item_forcast.xml**

**In your text view you have to add:** `android:minLines = "3"` and `android:maxLines = "3"`

It will keep the height of textView for 3 lines.

A sample TextView will look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" >
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_addesc"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:maxLines="3"
       android:minLines="3"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
       android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:** If the number of characters exceeds the 3 line limit then it will show text like below:

"
Hello world

Hello world

Hello world..."

Comment: I included the maxLines and minLines, but still it looks the same, No effect on output. ListView is in a fragment.It has string array to be displayed with some minHeight specified such as 75dp for example.

Comment: Can you share your full xml named **list_item_forcast.xml**

Comment: That is the complete list_item_forecast.xml file. It has only 1 TextView.

Comment: TextView cannot be an individual layout. A textView must be included inside of a Layout view. For example RelativeLayout or LinearLayout. I am updating my answer.

Comment: list_item_forecast.xml is a layout file with root view as TextView. Fragment.java code has line as below                                  ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,                                                               R.id.list_item_forecast_textView,weekForecast );